# About iOS10 animation

Tags: ios, animation

I'm coding a login view, when the keyboard show, background will move the same distance with an animation, but I find a question that I can't understand, when the animation begin, at the top of the background will display a white area, the white are is just the area that will disappear when the animation finished.

Here is my code

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification{
     CGRect keyboardBounds;
     [[notification.userInfo valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardBounds];
     NSNumber * duration = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey];
     NSNumber * curve = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey];
     keyboardBounds = [self.view convertRect:keyboardBounds toView:nil];
     CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
     viewFrame.origin.y = 0 - keyboardBounds.size.height;
     [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
     [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
     [UIView setAnimationDuration:[duration doubleValue]];
     [UIView setAnimationCurve:[curve intValue]];
     [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     self.bgView.frame = viewFrame;
     [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please place your code here?

Comment: OK, I have pasted my code.

Comment: Please remove your code from the answer section